# Swiper JS nuxt loading pages in SwiperSlide

Tags: nuxt.js, swiper.js

I'm currently trying to make a page carousel in Nuxt however where would I start? I've looked through the entire Swiper JS document and I'm not able to find anything on the docs.

I tried loading a page in SwiperSlide however It didn't load correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nuxt or Vue uses the same structure (see this example to do this https://swiperjs.com/vue)

a simple code:

```
<template>
  <swiper
    :slides-per-view="3"
    :space-between="50"
    @swiper="onSwiper"
    @slideChange="onSlideChange"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    ...
  </swiper>
</template>
<script>
  // Import Swiper Vue.js components
  import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

  // Import Swiper styles
  import 'swiper/css';

  export default {
    components: {
      Swiper,
      SwiperSlide,
    },
    setup() {
      const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
        console.log(swiper);
      };
      const onSlideChange = () => {
        console.log('slide change');
      };
      return {
        onSwiper,
        onSlideChange,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

To get a better answer send more details